# Using do-while twice?

Tags: java

I am having a concern and a problem with a school java code.
I have to do 3 parts:

A - make user entry a number, read it, verify if it's positive or negative using a boolean and then has to check, and just accept those be between 20 and 100. If not the program has to loop asking for an accepted number.

B - list the odd numbers between 0 and the number inserted and make the sum of them.

C - After making and running sections A and B, you must enter the necessary modifications to the program to be repeated twice to enter limit values and show their odd and the sum of these. That is, the sections will be repeated two times A + B.
You must use a do-while type structure to control it. (copy/pasted it)

Here is what I got at the moment:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class School_Proj1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number = 0;
        boolean positive = false;
        int sum = 0;

        do {
            System.out.print("Input a number: ");
            number = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
        } while(!positive && (number <20) || (number>100));

        System.out.println("Number input OK [ "+number+" ]"
            + "\n\nLet's go to the next phase!\n\n"
            + "The odd numbers until [ "+number+" ] are: ");

        for(int i=0; i <= number; i++){
            if (i%2 !=0){
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                sum = sum + i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nAnd the sum of the odd numbers until [ "+number+" ] are: " + sum);
    }
}
```

**My concern is: did I applied correctly the boolean there or it doesn't do nothing?**

**And the main problem is that I can't get the (C) part done. How can I use again a do-while and get it to do that?**

Thank you in advance! Any help is kindly accepted!

Comment: Your boolean `positive` does - effectively - nothing.  You are never assigning anything to it (other than the initial value of `false`.)

Comment: I was afraid of that but wanted to be wrong about it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, just add another loop and initialize sum at the right spot...

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number = 0;
    int sum;
    int entries = 0;
    boolean positive;

    do
    {
        sum = 0;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Input a number: ");
            number = scanner.nextInt();

            if (number < 0)
            {
                 positive = false;
            }
            else
            {
                 positive = true;
            }

            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        while ((positive == false) || (number < 20) || (number > 100));

        System.out.println("Number input OK [ " + number + " ]"
            + "\n\nLet's go to the next phase!\n\n"
            + "The odd numbers until [ " + number + " ] are: ");

        for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                sum = sum + i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nAnd the sum of the odd numbers until [ " + number + " ] are: " + sum);
    }
    while (++entries < 2);

}
```

Comment: Oh, I was somehow close. I was expecting something more complicated :-)
Thank you!
Can you please guide me with the boolean value too? Seems like where I placed it is wrong. :-s

Comment: I would simplify the code, all you need is to make sure someone enters a positive value.  The best code is simple to read.  Ill make an edit.

Comment: I am testing the code now and the one you posted worked but after the
`positive = number > 0;` @Andrej edited it is failing. It starts to accept any number (>20 | <100 does not work anymore).

Comment: try it again, i had a mistake in the exit logic of the while loop, i think it will have the desired affect.  If it works please up vote.  I need the points!

Comment: I agree with the code perfectly but we lost the boolean variable and in the statement they are asking me to use it. I will copy/paste the statement:
_To control if the entered value is correct or not, you must define a Boolean variable and evaluate it in the while._

Comment: Sorry for being such a pain :-/
If it were for me I only know how to verify that using a if statement (with the boolean). But I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You create `boolean` values from tests like:

```
number < 20
```

or

```
number > 100
```

or even

```
(number < 20) || (number > 100)
```

These `boolean` expressions can be assigned to `boolean` variables.

So you need:

> positive = number > 0;

Answer (score 0):

The positive is doing nothing because it is simply a variable set to false, and it is put in a conditional statement that checks

```
!false
```

, but it is always true! In fact you are checking if !false == true and it is always true.

Here there is no need to use a boolean, put

```
number <20 || number>100
```

in the do while and it is sufficient.

For c part add a do while that "wraps" your code, using an integer to count until you reach two cycles

```
cycle = 0;  
do { 
    cycle++;
    // your previous code  
} while (cycle < 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

boolean positive didn't do anything since it was never changed, for while(!positive ...), the first half will always be true. 
Also, the A question is kind of confusing: if it is between 20 and 100, it has to be positive, then why check + or - ? Change it to this might works

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class School_Proj1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number = 0;
    boolean positive = false;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0
do{
do {
    System.out.print("Input a number: ");
    number = scanner.nextInt();
    positive = (number > 0)? true:false;
} while(positive && !(number <= 20) || (number >= 100));

System.out.println("Number input OK [ "+number+" ]"
        + "\n\nLet's go to the next phase!\n\n"
        + "The odd numbers until [ "+number+" ] are: ");

for(int i=0; i <= number; i++){
    if (i%2 !=0){
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        sum = sum + i;
    }
}
  System.out.println("\nAnd the sum of the odd numbers until [ "+number+" ] are: " + sum);
}while(++count <= 2);
}
```